# How to use Perl's 'Digest' module to calculate CRC?

Tags: perl, crc, digest

I need to implement CRC-32 (with a custom polynomial) in Perl. I have seen that there is a module called [Digest::CRC](http://search.cpan.org/~olimaul/Digest-CRC-0.21/lib/Digest/CRC.pm) that does it. However, when I compare the result to an online calculator, I don't get the same CRC code.

---

My polynomial is "101101" (bin) or "2d" (hex)

My data is "1e5"

---

The online calculator is https://ghsi.de/CRC/index.php?Polynom=101101&Message=1e5. The result that I get from the calculator is "1010" (bin) or "A" (hex).

---

This is the Perl code that I have used (found somewhere on line)

---

```
use strict;

use warnings;

use Digest::CRC;

my $string = 0x01e5;

my $ctx = Digest::CRC->new(type => "crc32", poly => 0x2D);

$ctx->add($string);

print "CRC for '$string' is 0x" . $ctx->hexdigest . "\n";
```

---

This is the output of this Perl code:

CRC for '485' is 0x9d0fec86

---

I'm pretty sure that the online calculator is correct.

What is wrong with my Perl code?

Answer (score 4):

Your program is, as it says, calculating the CRC for the string `485` (bytes `34 38 35`), which is the decimal string representation for the number `0x1E5`. Meanwhile the web site is calculating the CRC for the bytes `01 e5`. I can't tell which one, if either, you want.

What is definitely true is that the web site isn't calculating any sort of CRC32, because its results aren't 32-bits long and seem to depend on the size of the polynomial you specify.

Also, if you use `Digest::CRC` specifying `type => 'crc32'` it will ignore all the other parameters and simply calculate a standard CRC32.

If you want a 32-bit CRC with a polynomial of 0x2D then you can try

```
my $ctx = Digest::CRC->new(width => 32, poly => 0x2D);
```

but there are several other things you need to define to specify a CRC, including (but not limited to) bit and byte order, initial value and end xor value, and there is no way of telling whether this will give you the correct checksum without seeing the full specification.

Surely you have a document that says something more than *"CRC32, polynomial 0x2d"*?

---

**Update**

> How can I use the `Digest::CRC` to treat the data as hex bytes and not as a string?

- `Digest::CRC` only processes strings and you need to pack your data that way. In this case you probably want `my $string = "\x01\xe5"`

> In addition, what is the "end xor value"?

- The `end xor` value is simply a bit pattern that is XORed with the result as the last step to get the final CRC.

> In addition If I understood you correctly, the following 2 methods should give the same result:

```
my $ctx1 = Digest::CRC->new(type => "crc32");
my $rr1 = $ctx1->add(pack 'H*', '1e5')->hexdigest;
print "a1=$rr1=\n";

my $ctx2 = Digest::CRC->new(width => 32, poly => 0x04c11db7);
my $rr2 = $ctx2->add(pack 'H*', '1e5')->hexdigest;
print "a2=$rr2=\n";
```

> However I get different results:

```
a1=fef37cd4= a2=758cce0=
```

> Can you tell me where is my mistake?

- As I said, there are many specifiers for a CRC. That is why you must establish the *full specification* of the CRC that you need, including more than just the width and the polynomial. To explicitly produce a CRC32 checksum you would need this

```
my $ctx = Digest::CRC->new(width => 32, poly => 0x04c11db7, init => 0xFFFFFFFF, xorout => 0xFFFFFFFF, refin => 1, refout => 1);
```

This applies initial and final values of `0xFFFFFFFF` and sets `refin` and `refout` to true. This reverses the bit order (*ref* is short for *reflect*) both before and after processing, and is the difference between MSB first and LSB first.

Comment: Thx Borodin, How can I use the digest::crc to treat the data as hex bytes and not as a string? in addition, what is the "end xor value"? Thx!

Comment: In addition

If I understood you correctly, the follwoing 2 methods, should give the same result:

<code>
my $ctx1 = Digest::CRC->new(type=>"crc32");
my $ctx2 = Digest::CRC->new(width=>32, poly=>0x04c11db7);

my $rr1 = $ctx1->add( pack 'H*', '1e5' )->hexdigest;
my $rr2 = $ctx2->add( pack 'H*', '1e5' )->hexdigest;

print "a1=$rr1=\n";
print "a2=$rr2=\n";
</code>

However I get different results:
<code>
a1=fef37cd4=
a2=758cce0=
</code>

Can you tell me where is my mistake?

Thx
Guy

Comment: @user2190993: I have updated my answer to answer your additional questions.

Comment: Thx, it worked.  Isn't there a better manual for the digest::CRC to fully understand the porpuse of all the parameters?  And if you can answer on how to work with data that is HEX and not ASCII. This is the data I need to run the CRC on.  Thx  (by the way, I'm new here and couln't finf a way to nicely format the comments. the <br/> didn't worked for me...)